# Sugar orm create table issue

Tags: android, sugarorm

First of all I have searched everywhere for a solution but I haven't found a solution for the common error on table creation:

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table:
>   EVENT (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO EVENT

My manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.something.something2">
        ...
        <meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="sugarexample.db" />
        <meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="4" />
        <meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="com.company.something.something2.Entities" />
```

My entity:

```
package com.company.something.something2.Entities;

import com.orm.SugarRecord;

public class Event extends SugarRecord {
    private String description;
    private String title;
    private String photo;
    public Event() {

    }

    //setters and getters
}
```

My Activity (for debugging):

```
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SugarContext.init(getApplicationContext());
        com.company.something.something2.Entities.Event book =
                new com.company.something.something2.Entities.Event();
        book.setId((long) 1);
        book.setTitle("test");
        book.setDescription("de");
        book.setPhoto("someurl");
        book.save();
```

What I have tried:

- Disabling Instant Run in Android Studio
- Removing DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME meta tag (someone suggested at some point)
- Changing it's value to `com.company.something.something2`
- Reinstalling the app
- Incrementing VERSION
- Renaming DATABASE value
- Creating a migration file to create the database

P.S: I am using SugarORM 1.5, Gradle 2.1.3

Does anyone have any ideeas?

Comment: try moving `SugarContext.init(getApplicationContext());` from your activity to your `Application` class

Comment: Thank you!!! Could you plese make it an answer to vote it? :)

Comment: Added the answer and my thoughts on the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your table is not created. SugarOrm requires a android **Application** class from which it can start creating or managing its table schemas and other necessary things.

As per your code, you have defined `SugarContext.init(getApplicationContext());` in your activity. This should be part of your **Application class** if your are not extending your class to **SugarApp** class.

Hence move this line to **onCreate** of Application class.
Also add following line in onTerminate()

```
 SugarContext.terminate();
```

Hence your Application class will look as follows:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SugarContext.init(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
        SugarContext.terminate();
    }
}
```

And declare this class in Androidmanifest.xml file

```
<application
  android:name=".MyApplication"
  .. rest of the code
```